# PHP Xdebug on Laravel 5.6 application not working

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

I work on Windows 10 with Laravel v5.6, PHP/php-fpm v7.2.4, and Xdebug v2.6.0.

My web site run locally. I installed the add-on Xdebug helper for Chrome and everything is done and configured as mentioned in this tutorial: 
[Laravel Development using PhpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm#LaravelDevelopmentusingPhpStorm-DebuggingLaravelApplicationswithPhpStorm)

However, Xdebug still can't working or debugging, and Xdebug not working for any reason, even when I click on debug button in PhpStorm, it will redirect me to the correct page but without any debugging.

Does anyone manage to debug Controllers or Models PHP code in a Laravel project and have the same issue?

Here are my Xdebug settings:

***php.ini***

**[xdebug]**

> zend_extension = c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll
>   xdebug.remote_enable = on
>   xdebug.profiler_enable = off
>   xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
>   xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
>   xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
>   xdebug.show_local_vars=0

***Problem:*** 
The result after run Xdebug, it move me to the right index page with session default values as following:

> http://localhost:8000/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=14610

but without any debugging on PhpStorm or any running process there.

This is my composer.json:

> ```
> "license": "MIT",
> "type": "project",
> "require": {
>     "php": ">=5.6.4",
>     "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
>     "laravelcollective/html": "5.6.*@dev",
>     "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^7.7",
>     "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
>     "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^2.3",
>     "zizaco/entrust": "1.7.*",
>     "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
>     "laravel/dusk": "^1.0",
>     "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.4",      
>     "intervention/image": "dev-master",
>     "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.0",
>     "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7",
>     "maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1",
>     "league/fractal": "^0.16.0",
>     "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.0",
>     "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0",
>     "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.11.*",
>     "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0",
>     "consoletvs/charts": "5.*",
>     "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
>     "mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator": "^2.0",
>     "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "5.4.*",
>     "tymon/jwt-auth": "^0.5.12",
>     "splitbrain/php-archive": "^1.0",
>     "laravel/cashier": "~7.0",
>     "maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar": "^1.3",
>     "gr8shivam/laravel-sms-api": "^2.0",
>     "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.4"
> },
> ```

Comment: 1) Show xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output. So far the settings you have provided do not give much info. BTW composer.json is not needed for this ... and Laravel 5.6 requires PHP 7.1+ .. so you composer requirements are a bit old... 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Troubleshooting+PhpStorm+debugging

Comment: Try adding ` xdebug.remote_connect_back` setting

Comment: also you don't appear to have set a port?

Comment: I tried to more figures to make it more clear, but I couldn't. Maybe because I'm still new here, then I need to get more reputation. Will try to add more details and figure later once I get the enough reputation.

Comment: At very least change xdebug port to `9001` in both php.ini and PhpStorm settings -- with php-fpm that quite likely will be the issue. Other than that -- collect xdebug log and provide your settings -- even reputation = 1 is enough to edit your own question and provide that info.

Comment: already solved, but working with simple code, not with MVC structure where the index file not exist. I think to run it on MVC structure and framework, one should try to configure XDEBUG on each project alone, to to use laravel debugger to solve the problem  .. 
Thanks for yr help :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my config:

```
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250
```

Usually the debug port is 9000, but if you use PHP-FPM the chances are it will already be on port 9000, so that's why I have it set to 9001.

Connect back setting allows you to trigger debugging via a browser bookmarklet or plugin button. Autostart starts a debug session every time, so I leave this off. The nesting level is for var_dumps etc, and lets you see more detail with less dots `...`.
I set the IDE key to PHPStorm, and set it in the IDE too along with the port.

That should be you good to go! Make sure your IDE is actually listening for a connection, and that in your browser via the button or bookmark that you have turned debugging on.

I use a nice XDebug helper for Firefox which toggles it.

Good luck!